# Django ValueError - add user to userteam

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a Django form where you can add a user to a UserTeam (UserTeams model below). The 'invite' page (below) queries the Team model to get the id of the current team, which it then assigns to 'teamID', so you can only add a user to the current team. (I have disabled this field so the user cannot change the team) The user then selects the user they want to add, and submits the form. I am trying this using the Team "Kate FC", and adding the player 'steven'. When I submit the form, however, i get this error:

ValueError at /teams/1/invite/

Cannot assign "'Kate FC'": "UserTeams.teamID" must be a "Team" instance.

What does this error mean??

```
class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    countryID = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)


def invite(request, teamID):
    try:
        query = Team.objects.get(id=teamID)
    except:
        raise Http404()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvitePlayerForm(request.POST or None, initial={'teamID': query})
        if form.is_valid():
            userteam = form.save(commit=False)
            userteam.save()
        return redirect('teammanager/teams.html')
    else:

        form = InvitePlayerForm(initial={'teamID': query})
        query = Team.objects.get(id=teamID)
    return render(request, 'teammanager/invite.html', {
        "team": query,                  
        "form": form
   })
```

the form:

```
    class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    teamID = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
    class Meta:

        model = UserTeams
        fields = ['teamID','userID']
```

Comment: Note that usually you would name your fields `team` and `user` (without ID), then you can access the ids with `team_id` and `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`teamID` is a foreign key, so you should use a model choice field instead of a CharField:

```
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    teamID = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), disabled=True)
    ...
```

or you could disable the field in the `__init__` method.

```
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvitePlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['teamID'].disabled = True
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could just leave the `teamID` field out of the form and set the value when you save the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    userteam = form.save(commit=False)
    userteam.teamID = query
    userteam.save()
```